# wp7 background process during application runs

Tags: windows-phone-7, backgroundworker, app.xaml

I have a project which includes many pages. I want to import information to my database periodically whatever the situation of my application is.

I tried to put my code inside App.xaml.cs but it is only saves data for once (I put it inside launching and tried in Constructor. My method is getting device id's location which is like

```
void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    Location loc = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);

    //Send Data to Database
    dclient.CreateUserLocationCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(dclient_CreateUserLocationCompleted);
    dclient.CreateUserLocationAsync(1, loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
}
```

and my watcher position changed is inside the constructor.

```
if (watcher == null)
{
    watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
}

MovementThreshold = getSelectedDeviceLocationFrequencyFromInternalFolder();

watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
watcher.Start();
```

and defined globally inside the App.xaml.cs

How can I run this periodically all the time while program runs ? Any other way ? Thanks (To sum up I want to insert the location data periodically to my database.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to launch a thread when the app launches that sleeps for whatever time it wants to (or wake up on a signal from the app - when the new value is received) and writes the data to your data store inside it.